# Прошу помочь разобраться как запись данные из json

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, android-room

Прошу помощи. Пытаюсь разобраться как реализовать сохранение в базу данных.
Получаю API с двух файлов, в одном секции (название, описание, иконка), в другом документы этих секций (к какой секции относиться, название, описание, иконка и url файла):

https://site/section/read.php

```
{
results: [
{
section_id: "1",
section_name: "NameSection_1",
section_description: "DescriptionSection_1",
section_icon: "https://site/data/image/img.png"
},
{
section_id: "2",
section_name: "NameSection_2",
section_description: "DescriptionSection_2",
section_icon: "https://site/data/image/img.png"
},
{
section_id: "3",
section_name: "NameSection_3",
section_description: "DescriptionSection_3",
section_icon: "https://site/data/image/img.png"
}
]
}
```

https://site/doc/read.php

```
{
results: [
{
section_id: "1",
doc_id: "1",
doc_name: "NameDoc_1",
doc_description: "DescriptionDoc_1",
doc_iconUrl: "https://site/data/image/img.png",
doc_linkUrl: "https://site/data/doc/doc.pdf"
},
{
section_id: "1",
doc_id: "2",
doc_name: "NameDoc_2",
doc_description: "DescriptionDoc_2",
doc_iconUrl: "https://site/data/image/img.png",
doc_linkUrl: "https://site/data/doc/doc.pdf"
},
{
section_id: "2",
doc_id: "3",
doc_name: "NameDoc_3",
doc_description: "DescriptionDoc_3",
doc_iconUrl: "https://site/data/image/img.png",
doc_linkUrl: "https://site/data/doc/doc.pdf"
},
section_id: "2",
doc_id: "4",
doc_name: "NameDoc_4",
doc_description: "DescriptionDoc_4",
doc_iconUrl: "https://site/data/image/img.png",
doc_linkUrl: "https://site/data/doc/doc.pdf"
},
{
section_id: "3",
doc_id: "5",
doc_name: "2586р",
doc_description: "DescriptionDoc_4",
doc_iconUrl: "https://site/data/image/img.png",
doc_linkUrl: "https://site/data/doc/doc.pdf"
}
]
}
```

Идея такая: открывается приложение, проверяется если изменения в api, если нет - ничего не делаем, если есть - обновляем базу данных (записываем данные и скачиваем документ, сохраняем путь к документу). Как это реализовать не знаю.

Пишу на kotlin, архитектура MVVM. Хочу использовать room и retrofit. Но не уверен что с помощью retrofit можно скачивать файлы.
Подскажите с чего начать. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Начните снизу, т.е. с Room и определения Entity для ваших данных. Возможно будет достаточно двух: Section и Document. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data

Comment: Потом доступ к ним: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data

Comment: И только потом можно переходить к MVVM и Retrofit.